# asset pipeline error but config.assets.enabled = false in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am deploying a first rails app via capistrano with:
rails 3.1 
passenger 3.0.11
nginx 1.0.10

The app errors out. In my $app/logs/production.log, I get:

```
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
8:   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__88091947956529734_37470040'
```

But in my application.rb, I have set:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

I thought this directive causes the asset pipeline to be disabled. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

With the pipeline disabled, Rails is expecting the referenced files `application.css` and `application.js` to be available in the public directory at the pre-3.1 locations.

Is there a reason why you are not using the pipeline?