# Correct assets relative url: rails/apache/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm testing  rails app deployment with apache2 and  phusion passenger 4.
This is my apache conf:

```
    <Location /myproject>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
    </Location>
```

then I start passenger in standalone mode in myproject directory:

```
passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d
```

When I point my browser to https://mydomain.com/myproject the  home page shows up correctly but no css or js is loaded because the links to the assets are like:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

which points to:

```
https://mydomain.com/assets/application.css
```

but should be:

```
https://mydomain.com/myproject/assets/application.css
```

How can fix this on apache or rails side?

Comment: i can use map '/myproject' do  in config.ru to remap the base url but this will not fix the url to the assets

Comment: if I set config.assets.enabled = false and config.asset_path = proc { |path| "/myproject#{path}" } in application.rb
i will get correct path to my assets but tey will not be generated automatically. how can this be avoided?

Comment: If you are using rails 3.1 or later, are you precompiling your assets?

Comment: Yes, I already ran rake assets:clean and rake assets:precompile, the problem is that if you set config.assets.enabled = false only application.css and application.js are present in the page's header.

Comment: That's correct.  If you set that to false, then you are no longer using the asset pipeline, therefore the paths will no longer work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389204/asset-pipeline-error-but-config-assets-enabled-false-in-application-rb

Answer (score 2):

The solution was simple:

```
config.relative_url_root = "/myproject"
```

in application.rb

this fixed path of the assets without disabling the assets pipeline.

Comment: I just tested this in Passenger 4, Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.1.6 and I had to add also: config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myproject"